# Can't create index due to TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, pymongo

I am trying to create indices with pymongo, but failing with error

```
File "D:/Users/Dims/Design/EnergentGroup/Python GIS Developer/worker/Approach03\sentinel\mongo.py", line 46, in get_results_collection
    results_collection.create_index(["uwi", "date_part"], name=index_name, unique=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1386, in create_index
    name = kwargs.setdefault("name", helpers._gen_index_name(keys))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 49, in _gen_index_name
    return _UUNDER.join(["%s_%s" % item for item in keys])
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 49, in <listcomp>
    return _UUNDER.join(["%s_%s" % item for item in keys])
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Apparently, error occurs inside the library in the code creating default index name, which is

```
def _gen_index_name(keys):
    """Generate an index name from the set of fields it is over."""
    return _UUNDER.join(["%s_%s" % item for item in keys])
```

apparently incorrect.

My code is following:

```
index_name = 'uwi_date_part'
if index_name not in index_information:
    print("Creating index '%s'..." % index_name)
    results_collection.create_index(["uwi", "date_part"], name=index_name, unique=True)

index_name = 'uwi'
if index_name not in index_information:
    print("Creating index '%s'..." % index_name)
    results_collection.create_index("uwi", name=index_name, unique=False)
```

How to overcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax is not what PyMongo requires:

```
results_collection.create_index(["uwi", "date_part"], name=index_name, unique=True)
```

You want an index on the two fields, "uwi" and "date_part"? Choose carefully what order to index the fields in (see [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/)) and whether to index them in ascending or descending order.

If you want to index "uwi" and "date_part" in that order, both ascending, then do this:

```
results_collection.create_index([("uwi", 1), ("date_part", 1)], name=index_name, unique=True)
```

[For more info on creating indexes with PyMongo, see the documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index).