# How I can solve this problem pymongo.errors.OperationFailure?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to do a title search in my database, but I can't.

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://LOGIN:PASS@cluster0.ye4cx.mongodb.net/info?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE")
mydb = myclient["info"]
mycol = mydb["comics"]

find = mycol.find({"title": {"$search": "68"}})

for f in find:
    print(f)
```

But I get this error

```
raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response,
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unknown operator: $search, full error: {'operationTime': Timestamp(1601923289, 13), 'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'unknown operator: $search', 'code': 2, 'codeName': 'BadValue', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1601923289, 13), 'signature': {'hash': b'\x82\x91\xc5\xd4r\xd6\xbf\xbc\x13i\xe5\x83b\xd2\x9eUv\xb8\x89/', 'keyId': 6869109962937729027}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `$text` operator to make it work. Don't forget to create an index on the title field.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import TEXT

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://LOGIN:PASS@cluster0.ye4cx.mongodb.net/info?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE")
mydb = myclient["info"]
mycol = mydb["comics"]

#Creating index on title
mycol.create_index([('title', TEXT)], default_language='english')

find = mycol.find({"$text": {"$search": "68"}})

for f in find:
    print(f)
```

This will search all the indexed fields and return the matching ones. See more details on [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/).

Comment: I try it too, but `raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response,
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: text index required for $text query, full error: {'operationTime': Timestamp(1601927775, 17), 'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'text index required for $text query', 'code': 27, 'codeName': 'IndexNotFound', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1601927775, 17), 'signature': {'hash': b'ZUV\xbez\xedh\xb6\xaa\xb3\xcd)$\xa2\xee\xda\xfbu\x85\xe7', 'keyId': 6869109962937729027}}}`

Comment: @fungalspores, you need to create index on your title field.

Comment: I have new trouble `raise TypeError("'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to "
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'createIndex' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.`

Comment: @fungalspores
This is because pymongo has `create_index` function and not createIndex.

Comment: I think that is lasr problem `raise TypeError("if no direction is specified, "
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list`

Comment: @fungalspores, seems like it, you can try it as a list: `collection.create_index([('title', TEXT)], default_language='english')`. You will have to import TEXT from pymongo.

Comment: `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: @fungalspores this error occurs when we pass keys only with other arguments without the list.
Currently, there's nothing wrong with the syntax mentioned above. If the problem persists, I would recommend you to use mongo shell for creating indices: `db.stores.createIndex( { title: "text" } )`
or you may use RoboMongo for the same command.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/

Comment: Can you help me, please. Use this topic for my code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564974/cant-create-index-due-to-typeerror-not-enough-arguments-for-format-string

Comment: @fungalspores, yes I can. Testing script on local.

Comment: You can't do it too?

Comment: @fungalspores, I was busy in tasks. I'll do it today and will update the script.
Can you tell me your pymongo, python and mongodb versions?

Comment: @fungalspores I have tested my script and it's working fine. I am using MongoDB 4.2.9, python 3.6.9 and pymongo 3.11.0.
Exact script is updated as well.

Comment: @fungalspores, you're welcome. Don't forget to accept and upvote ;)

Comment: I can't upvote(new account), but I accept you answer

Comment: @fungalspores, it's okay. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$search is an aggregation pipeline operator. See  https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/query-syntax/#query-syntax-ref for correct usage. It cannot be specified in a find query.